# Toggle element by class name

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to toggle (hide/show)  several elements of my web page.

All those elements are in between this tag:

```
 <div class="class_name">to toggle</div> 
 <div class="class_name">to toggle2</div>
```

I would like to use javascript to toggle all the elements with class=class_name when the user clicks on a button.

So far all the code I found only hides div by ID.

I am working with ruby on rails, so if there is a way not to write the js code and not create new functions I would appreciate. I would also like a way to call visual effects but on class and not id.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with Ruby on Rails but on Wikipedia it says that it uses the prototype.js library. Are you using prototype.js? JavaScript libraries enable you to select elements by class-name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery:

```
$('.class_name').toggle();
```

Comment: Almost tempted to downvote for suggesting jQuery when the question mentions nothing about it, but doing *anything* by class name in JS is *so* painful.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually working, but in my case the div's are in a table, and weirdly it does not apply to them. Any clue on how I could have that working?

Comment: This code will work for any elements with that class, anywhere.  Check the class name

Comment: It does not seem to work in that case: <table><tr>
<div class="contract_row" >
<td>
  hello
</td>
</div>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: So if I understand well, the only way to hide a row is to hide every single cell of it?

Comment: You can hide the `<tr>` itself.  For example: `$('.someClass').parent()` or `$('tr:has(.someCLass)')`.  See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 1):

Rails comes with [prototype library](http://www.prototypejs.org/) out of the box. All you have to do to use it is add this line in `<head>` part of your layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Then you can use this call to toggle elements by class name:

```
$$('.class_name').each(Element.toggle);
```